# Expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Expand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$ in ascending of power of $x$, up to and including the term in $x^2$, simplifying the coefficient. Hence find the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion of $\frac{1+2x}{\sqrt{4-16x}}$

My attempt, $(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

$=1+(-\frac{1}{2})(-4x)+\frac{(-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})}{2!}(-4x)^2$

$=1+2x+6x^2$

How to proceed to the next part by using the result of first part?

Comment: Hint $\sqrt{4-16x}=2\sqrt{1-4x}$

Comment: By the way, $(1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 1 + 2x + 6x^2 + o(x^2) \neq  1 + 2x + 6x^2$.

Comment: @tired. I cant get the answer which is 5.

Comment: See [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ [x^2]\frac{1+2x}{\sqrt{4-16 x}} = \frac{1}{2}[x^2]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}+[x]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\tag{1} $$
and since:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} = 1+2x+6x^2+O(x^3)\tag{2} $$
we have:
$$ [x^2]\frac{1+2x}{\sqrt{4-16 x}} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 6+2=\color{red}{5}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: How can I expand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}$ ? @Jack D'Aurizio